# Selecting subfolders from a set of folder and renaming

Tags: linux, shell, rename

So here it is i will be having a folder full of subfolders with file names **0.0001** , **0.0002** and so on continuing to **0.001**, **0.002** and till **0.1**.
My task is to batch rename these folders to **1,2,3,4,5** and so on till **1000**. But apart from these folders there will be some auxillary folders with names like **blahblah** and so on. I am supposed to choose only the folders with **0.*** and rename them. I tried the following but didn't work;

```
j=1 
for i in *
do
    if [ "$i" = "0.*" ]
    then
       mv "$i" "$j"
    fi
    ((j++))
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `for i in *` use

```
for i in 0.*/
do
    mv "$i" "$j"
done
```

Comment: To get the desired folder names, use `newname=$(echo "($i * 10000)/1"|bc)` See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89712/bash-float-to-integer